Any fix to AMD gpu with Davinci Resolve?
The AMD driver is installed but still cant open the DR with this errors:
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve 
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0

And the GPU is already running
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=2560,1440
       resources: irq:148 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f00000

